# UIPageViewController transition (passing through viewcontroller before the target viewcontroller)

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10, uipageviewcontroller

Let`s say i have 3 or more view controllers in pageViewController.

If i go to third view controller from my first view controller, the transition is directly to Third view controller without passing through second View controller.

I`m using this code to make the transition:

```
            let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)
            self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? 
            [UIViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is it possible to getting through the second view controller like this animation?
https://github.com/calvinsug/SlidingContainerViewController